# Request a PTR record for google DNS (8.8.8.8)

Tags: ip, network-discovery, tcpdump

When I request a A record for a domain, eg: `host google.com` and display packets by tcpdump. I notice that my system also requested a PTR record for DNS nameserver (8.8.8.8 in this case).

```
09:53:42.775298 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.9455 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 43173+ A? google.com. (28)
09:53:42.775318 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.9455 > google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain: 43173+ A? google.com. (28)
09:53:42.775910 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.51957 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 59481+ PTR? 8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa. (38)
09:53:42.871087 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > markstevens-Linux-System.local.9455: 43173 12/0/0 A 113.171.252.231, A 113.171.252.210, A 113.171.252.217, A 113.171.252.251, A 113.171.252.223, A 113.171.252.238, A 113.171.252.245, A 113.171.252.230, A 113.171.252.244, A 113.171.252.237, A 113.171.252.216, A 113.171.252.224 (220)
09:53:42.871781 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.11540 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 30293+ AAAA? google.com. (28)
09:53:42.877560 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > markstevens-Linux-System.local.51957: 59481 1/0/0 PTR google-public-dns-a.google.com. (82)
09:53:42.877843 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.49496 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 34137+ PTR? 2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (42)
09:53:42.880061 IP google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain > markstevens-Linux-System.local.9455: 43173 16/0/0 A 113.171.246.104, A 113.171.246.123, A 113.171.246.118, A 113.171.246.109, A 113.171.246.84, A 113.171.246.93, A 113.171.246.88, A 113.171.246.119, A 113.171.246.114, A 113.171.246.94, A 113.171.246.103, A 113.171.246.108, A 113.171.246.98, A 113.171.246.99, A 113.171.246.89, A 113.171.246.113 (284)
09:53:42.969118 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > markstevens-Linux-System.local.11540: 30293 1/0/0 AAAA 2404:6800:4005:809::200e (56)
09:53:42.969505 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.16015 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 5941+ MX? google.com. (28)
09:53:42.975088 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > markstevens-Linux-System.local.49496: 34137 NXDomain 0/0/0 (42)
09:53:43.075493 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > markstevens-Linux-System.local.16015: 5941 5/0/0 MX alt4.aspmx.l.google.com. 50, MX aspmx.l.google.com. 10, MX alt3.aspmx.l.google.com. 40, MX alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. 20, MX alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. 30 (136)
```

I want to ask why it must requests a PTR request for DNS nameserver when It could sends a request to exact nameserver before (two first lines) as I configure in network-manager.

[image]

Addition, in dumpfile, I notice that my system also requested a PTR record for my local IP (192.168.1.2), why it requests that?

```
09:53:42.877843 IP markstevens-Linux-System.local.49496 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 34137+ PTR? 2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (42)
```

thanks for reading !

Comment: NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. This question seems to be more related to applications and how they functions rather than a question about networks, even if they do use a network. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that tcpdump is printing host names, you didn't run it with the `-n` flag.

Therefore, it tries to resolve the source and destination IP addresses of packets when it prints them - and, as it's printing host names, it succeeds.

In order to do that, it calls routines that...

> I want to ask why it must requests a PTR request for DNS nameserver
>
> ...
>
> I notice that my system also requested a PTR record for my local IP (192.168.1.2)

...send out PTR requests for the IP addresses in question.

I.e., the "it" that's requesting that is tcpdump, and it's doing so because you ran it without the `-n` flag and it's seeing network traffic to or from 8.8.8.8 and traffic to or from 192.168.1.2.

Comment: Ok, I understood it, I tried again with -n option and tcpdump not try to resolve source IP(192.168.1.2) and destination IP (8.8.8.8) Thanks